# Should I use Objects to avoid method overloading or method overloading is better?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I have two interface structures.

### MyInterface1

```
public interface MyInterface1{

public Object SUM(Object O,Object P);

}
```

### MyInterface2

```
public interface MyInterface2{

public int SUM(int O,int P);
public double SUM(int O,double P);
public double SUM(double O,double P);
public double SUM(double O,int P);

}
```

Which is a better design approach to implement the interface so that code efficiency is maintained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second approach (overloading) is much more preferred since it contains method signatures that are strongly typed.

Think about the following code.

```
public class InterfaceImpl implements MyInterface2{

    public Object SUM(Object O,Object P){
        //Really what can I do here without casting?

        /* If I have to cast, I might as well define
         types in the method signature, guaranteeing
         the type of the arguments
        */

       //Lets cast anyway
       return (Integer) O + (Integer) P;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
       System.out.println(SUM(1,2));  //Excellent Returns 3
       //Yikes, valid arguments but implementation does not handle these
       System.out.println(SUM(true,false)); //Class cast exception          
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

As more types are encountered that the method needs to handle, the implementation will be forced to perform type checking before doing the necessary casts.  In theory type checking would need to occur for every class that extends Object, since the method signature only restrains arguments to the type.  Since the arguments are objects there will be an infinite amount of types to check, rather impossible.

By using overloaded methods you express the intent of the method as well as restrict the set of allowable types.  This makes writing the implementation of the method much easier and manageable, since arguments will be strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers already mentioned, overloading is better.

But I would also add that you don't need 4 versions, only 2:

```
public interface MyInterface2 {
  public int SUM(int O, int P);
  public double SUM(double O, double P);
}
```

If you call `SUM` with an (int,double) or (double,int) the int will get upcasted to a double and the second of the methods is the one that will run.

For example, the code below compiles and prints "goodbye":

```
public class Test implements MyInterface2 {
  public int SUM(int o, int p) {
    System.err.println("hello");
    return o + p;
  }

  public double SUM(double o, double p) {
    System.err.println("goodbye");
    return o + p;
  }

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.SUM(1.0, 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case second option is good. But it varies from code to code. Example

```
interface InterfaceFrequencyCounter
{
    int getCount(List list, String name);
}

interface AnotherInterfaceFrequencyCounter
{
    int getCount(ArrayList arrayList, String name);
    int getCount(LinkedList linkedList, String name);
    int getCount(Vector vector, String name);
}
```

so now in above given case second option is not good practice. First one is good.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is better, as you don't want someone to call you method with a `String` or something.

What you can do, is using a common super class if you have one (`Number` in your case - if you wish to get Long and Float too).

Answer (score 0):

For safe code method overloading better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is better as described above.

If you run into a situation described by AmitG, you should use interfaces and not just the most generic object type. Anyways, your method almost always can work properly with only some subset of objects, not all of them. In that case you need to find a common interface and use it in a method signature, just like AmitG did in his example. The use of interface shows your intent to method cliens clearly, it's typesafe and removes the need to do casting inside the method.